# Live streaming using darwing streaming server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have set up a darwin streaming server on my mac.
now i need to stream these videos on my iphone real time

but the problems is the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is called even before the videos are played

i have checked the server its up and running
also i have successfully opened the url's in safari and quicktime.
but the videos just wont be played on the simulator
the code i have written is

```
NSURL *movieURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"rtsp://10.41.37.160/sample_300kbit.mov"];
// NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://10.41.37.160/sample_300kbit.mp4"];
if (movieURL != nil) 
{
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];      

    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.fullscreen=YES;
   // moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(endPlay:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit; 
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
    [moviePlayer play];
    //[self reloadInputViews];
}

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
{  


self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = FALSE;
moviePlayer = [notification object];
[moviePlayer play];
}

-(void)endPlay: (NSNotification*)notification
{ 

NSLog(@"end Playing");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer stop];
[moviePlayer release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any documentation to back up this up, but you can't play RTSP streams on iOS.

You've got to use HTTP (either direct to a movie file, or using HTTP live streaming). I don't think Darwin Streaming Server can do HLS, but you can serve a straight movie file using an ordinary web server.

Note that the codecs that the video can use are [somewhat limited](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW20)...

Comment: i guess your right. but it is supported on android 
so i was guessing it might be supported on iOS as well